# How to generate button with event and table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I generate table with jquery and I generate button and put it in each row of this table I want to set event for that buttons that whenever each of them clicked remove that particular row which that button is in there
here is my code:

```
$("#table_sample").append("<tr>" +
    "<td>" + value1 + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + value2 + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + value3 + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "<button type='button' class='col-sm-7 btn btn-danger pull-right'>delete</button> " +
    "</td></tr>");
```

Is there any way that can set event for each of them that can delete their rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.closest()` to grab the parent row of the clicked button,

```
$('#table_sample').on('click','tr td :button:contains(delete)',function(e){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

And note that we have used [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) here, since those buttons are being created at the runtime.

**Special note:** I have used the `:contains()` selector here, because I don't know the exact identity of those buttons, you must have some common identifiable class to them, use that instead.

Comment: GRRRR, I was about to answer the exact same thing. WHY ARE YOU SO FAST :P

Comment: @ahmadalbayati ah damn, i didn't even see that answer... my net is dead slow :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to target the parent row.

```
$("#table_sample").on('click','.btn-danger',function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Note that you also neeed to delegate the event on dynamically created elements using the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method (*Assuming you're using jQuery version 1.71 or later*)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function ()
{
    var test = $('<button/>',
    {
        text: 'Test',
        click: function () { alert('hi'); }
    });

    var parent = $('<tr><td></td></tr>').children().append(test).end();

    $("#addNodeTable tr:last").before(parent);
});
```

Or,

```
$("#myButton").click(function ()
{    
    var test = $('<button/>',
    {
        text: 'Test',
        click: function () { alert('hi'); }
    }).wrap('<tr><td></td></tr>').closest('tr');

    $("#addNodeTable tr:last").before(test);
});
```